# How to have a Timer whose time keeps changing in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, timer

I have a timer setup like this. I want the Timer to be reset and reinitialized with the new timevalue as and when `changingTimeValue` changes. What are the ways in which I can do this ?

```
snakeUpdateTimer = Timer.periodic( changingTimeValue , (timer){
      snakeBloc.add(SnakeMoveEvent()) ;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Timer snakeUpdateTimer;

...

set changingTimeValue(Duration duration) {
    snakeUpdateTimer?.cancel();
    snakeUpdateTimer = Timer(
      duration,
      () => snakeBloc.add(SnakeMoveEvent()),
    );
  }

...

RaisedButton(
  child: Text("Click to reset Timer"),
  onPressed: (){
    changingTimeValue= Duration(seconds: 3);
  },
)
```

When you assign `Duration` to `changingTimeValue`, it will cancel the old timer and creates new one.

If you also want to periodically reset the timer after timeout, then use

```
set changingTimeValue(Duration duration) {
  snakeUpdateTimer?.cancel();
  snakeUpdateTimer = Timer.periodic(
    duration,
    (timer) => snakeBloc.add(SnakeMoveEvent()), 
    //timer contains number of cycles finished(timer.tick)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Timer.periodic constructor](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html) or [Timer constructor](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-async/Timer/Timer.html). Timer.periodic is initialized once with the duration and it invokes the callback on the intervals that is provided as duration. Whereas Timer constructor creates a timer that ticks only once. Based on your requirement you can used any of these.

Following is the code that allows you to change the time of the timer:

```
Timer _timer; // global variable.

void updateTimerDuration(Duration changingTimeValue) {
  if (_timer != null && _timer.isActive) _timer.cancel();

  // if you want timer to tick only once.
  _timer = Timer(changingTimeValue, () {
    snakeBloc.add(SnakeMoveEvent());
  });

  // if you want timer to tick at fixed duration.
  _timer = Timer.periodic(changingTimeValue, (timer) {
    snakeBloc.add(SnakeMoveEvent());
  });
}
```

I hope it helps, in case of any doubts please comment.

Comment: Please show me the code as to how to implement the time change handling.

Comment: I have updated my answer, hope it helps you. In case of doubt please let me know. And if it works for you then please accept and up-vote this answer.